# I cannot import or export anything in Blender. It throws

Tags: export, import, error

I am not able to do anything in Blender. Every time I try to either export or import or install an add-on, Blender throws an error saying, "ImportError: This file should not be accessible in Python 3. Either you are trying to run from the python-future src folder or your installation of python-future is corrupted."

I have no idea what it means. So this is what I've done-

1.Reinstalled Blender.

2.Uninstalled Python 2.7 in Laptop.

3.Installed Python 3 again.

4.Uninstalled Python 3 and installed Python 2.7.

None of them worked.

Here are the screenshots.

**Importing**
[image: Importing fbx from makehuman export]

**Exporting**
[image: Export fbx]

**Add-On**
[image: Installing BlenderMada Add-On]

Please let me know what is to be done to rectify this and please ask anything you need.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

It worked after I installed Python3 and added it to the PATH as specified in the link - https://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/pythonpath.php

Comment: you have python 2.7 installed on your system, remove that and blender will work. You do not need to install any python, it comes bundled with blender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender is definately running its own version of python, which is python 3.
You get that error message because your "Blender Python" is trying to import reprlib and it should find that file in the Blender python directory, which in your case is "F:\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\2.79\python\lib\reprlib.py". Make sure this file exists.

For some reason your Blender Python doesn't find that file and looks elsewhere. You might have misconfigured your Scripts directory in Blender. Check you preferences, they should look like this:
[image: Blender preferences for python scripts directory]

Uninstalling and reinstalling probably didn't help because the preferences will not be deleted as they are stored in you application data directory.

If that's not the problem, then there is probably something wrong with your environment variables for python. Check your environment variables as described in this link:
https://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/pythonpath.php